# Woocommerce: disable payment method with cost on delivery

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem when I select cost on delivery as shipment method: the paypal button doesn't disappear, so the user could pay twice and this is a undesirable behaviour.

I've attached an image to clarify my problem because I'm searching the web but I don't find the solution.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You can try it because I know javascript and jQuery. The only problem is that I don't know what file I need to modify...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way how to do this is through jQuery. Put inside the  of your document the following

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then find the file where the checkout page is setup and enter the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('input[name=your_radio_name]:checked').val() == "the value when the element should be hidden") {
        $('#id_of_the_element_that_should_be_hidden').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: yes, but the problem is that the checkbox appears after an AJAX call, so I need to know where is that ajax request in order to put that code...

Comment: you have to look in your code for that. And when you find it include the above command when the ajax content has been parsed in the document without the $(document)ready