# Woocommerce delivery&payment options - What´s wrong with my php code?

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I am trying to hide some payment options in Woocommerce in case of specific delivery option. I tried to put this to my functions.php but It´s not working and I don´t know why.
Can you help me please?

```
    function payment_gateway_disable_country( $available_gateways, $available_methods )
    {
    global $woocommerce;
    if ( isset( $available_methods['local_delivery'] ) ){
    unset( $available_gateways['paypal'] );
    }
    return $available_gateways;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateway_disable_country' );
```

My research:

[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448143/woocommerce-disable-payment-method-with-cost-on-delivery)

[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832317/woocommerce-payment-methods)

[link 3](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/restrict-payment-options-based-on-product?replies=27)

[link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015173/how-to-hide-payment-method-in-woocommerce-based-on-postal-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The available delivery methods do not get passed as a parameter in the filter `woocommerce_available_payment_gateways` - you need to load them in and check them.

The code below should remove the paypal payment option one if the user selects local delivery. If your checkout page is the AJAX based one then as the user changes the delivery method, the available payment options should also change.

```
function payment_gateway_disable_country($available_gateways) {

    global $woocommerce;

    $packages = $woocommerce->shipping->get_packages();

    foreach ( $packages as $i => $package ) {
        $chosen_method = isset( $woocommerce->session->chosen_shipping_methods[ $i ] ) ?
            $woocommerce->session->chosen_shipping_methods[ $i ] :  '';

        if ('local_delivery' == $chosen_method) {  
            unset($available_gateways['paypal']);
            break;
        }
    }

    return $available_gateways;

}

add_filter(
    'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways',
    'payment_gateway_disable_country'
);
```

Let me know if you have any issues with the code; I did not have a chance to test it with woocommerce.

Comment: Thank you for answer but Unfortunately It's still not working, don´t know why... Still same result, nothing has changed...

Comment: Ah, very sorry - some mistakes on my part. Incorrect syntax for the latest version of Woocommerce, also I forgot that the shipping selector and the list of payment gateways is usually shown on the same page, so there is no shipping method selected.

Updated the code so that it now doesn't display paypal if local_delivery is one of the available shipping methods. Have tested this and it is working for me.

Comment: Just made another update - if you're using the AJAX checkout page then the available payment gateways will now update when the user changes their shipping option

Comment: I'm sorry but I can not get it to work, I pasted the code into functions.php, replaced the old one but still nothing.. Here is the site: http://vobart.cz/pokladna/ (shipping: "Na dobirku" is "local delivery" and when selected, paypal is still active and visible...

Comment: What version of woocommerce are you running? You could try adding `error_log("running");` to the function and then checking your error log when you visit the checkout page?

Comment: I am running version 2.1.7 and I am sorry but I don´t know what I should exactly do with: error_log("running"); I am kind of noob...

Comment: I just tested on the same version and it is working for me. Do you know how to check your php error log?

Comment: I am afraid that no, can you help me with that please?

Comment: Maybe you should install a wordpress plugin to show the PHP error log - how about this one - http://wordpress.org/plugins/error-log-monitor/

Comment: I done it, what now? I tried to browse my website for a while and log file is still whole blank.

Comment: Ok, I added some debug messages to the function - https://gist.github.com/madebydavid/11291518 Try that code there and then look at your error log

Comment: OK, I placed the log file into the right directory but It´s still empy after browsing my website..

Comment: Hi, I finally got some log report so here it is: [26-Apr-2014 10:36:54 UTC] payment_gateway_disable_country is running
[26-Apr-2014 10:36:54 UTC] current shipping method is 
[26-Apr-2014 10:36:54 UTC] returning
[26-Apr-2014 10:37:42 UTC] payment_gateway_disable_country is running
[26-Apr-2014 10:37:42 UTC] current shipping method is 
[26-Apr-2014 10:37:42 UTC] returning

Comment: I think that selected shipping method is not recognized by script? And then, paypal method is not removed...

Comment: Yes, you are correct, it is not recognising the shipping method. I am investigating why.

Comment: Hey, I have updated the code here - https://gist.github.com/madebydavid/11291518 please could you try this? I think you are running a newer version of woocommerce than me so please let me know if it works and I will update the questions.

Comment: Hi, thank you for everything, It´s working finally :) Thank you for your patience with me and thank you for your help, I appreciate it, you are the number one ;)

Comment: Happy it works! I will update my answer with the correct code!

Answer (score 0):

`$available_methods` will not be accessible inside your function. So first define it globally & access as global variable inside function, somewhat like this:

```
global $available_methods;
$available_methods = array( 'local_delivery' => 'yes' );

function payment_gateway_disable_country( $available_gateways )
{
global $woocommerce, $available_methods;
if ( isset( $available_methods['local_delivery'] ) ){
unset( $available_gateways['paypal'] );
}
return $available_gateways;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateway_disable_country' );
```

Comment: I'm guessing he wants to get the delivery method that the user has selected - not just the value from some hard-coded array.

Comment: I need only COD payment gateway for local delivery option and for another delivery options BACS and PAYPAL payment gateways. I tried Ratnakar´s solution and still no changes.

Comment: @madebydavid I wanted to point out that 2nd argument will not work, as user has mentioned in his question. Either he need to access by setting it globally or the best option, he should try your solution

Comment: @user2295265 you should try madebydavid's solution, it is working, I tested it